# How to filter the array of dic- filter and append to separate array of dic

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, filter

I have one array of dic, in my dic i have one key's  called "state": test, "state" : original. I may have multiple object.

code:

```
var StatusData = [[String: Any]]()
var testStatusData = [[String: Any]]()
var originalStatusData = [[String: Any]]()
```

My small snippet in my method :

Where ->  `document.data() is an [String:Any]`

```
for document in (querySnapshot! as AnyObject).documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    let data  = document.data()
                    self.playersStatusData.append(document.data())
                }
                print(self.playersStatusData)
```

Now i need to add the filter for `playersStatusData`, and based on the state - test, original. I need to seperate the object and append to their respective array of dic.

if i have 4 object of dic in my `playersStatusData` . In that if 2 object are having state = "test". Then that particular object alone needs to append to `testStatusData`.

same another 2 object having state = "original". Then that particular object alone needs to append to `originalStatusData`.

i used `filter { $0.1 == "orginal" }`. Its just printing only that key, values. But i need full object and append to their respective  [String: Any]].

Any help on that, thanks.

Update :

```
 [“test”: 1, “id”: 230, “total”: 1, “crunch”: 1, “name”: Cristina Criado, "Bot": <null>, "state": test,]

 [“test”: 3, “id”: 20, “total”: 10, “crunch”: 1, “name”: phasni, "Bot": <null>, "state": original,]

[“test”: 5, “id”: 0, “total”: 00, “crunch”: 1, “name”:picturn, "Bot": <null>, "state": test,]
```

Comment: Add your data structure in post.

Comment: @dahiya_boy  updated, please check it out

Comment: What  `document.data()` and `playersStatusData ` contains ?

Comment: `playersStatusData`  is [[String:Any]] ...just i appended all the dic values to array of dic. And `document.data()` is [String:Any] which i will get from firestore data.

Comment: Are you applying the filter on `data`?

Comment: i tried for both data, playersStatusData. But its just giving that particular key values like [status : test]. But i want to append all the object with the matching key values with the respective array of dic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
let playersStatusData =  [
    ["test": 1, "id": 230, "total": 1, "crunch": 1, "name": "A", "Bot": "", "state": "test"],
    ["test": 2, "id": 231, "total": 1, "crunch": 1, "name": "B", "Bot": "", "state": "original"],
    ["test": 3, "id": 232, "total": 1, "crunch": 1, "name": "C", "Bot": "", "state": "test"],
    ["test": 4, "id": 233, "total": 1, "crunch": 1, "name": "D", "Bot": "", "state": "original"],
    ["test": 5, "id": 234, "total": 1, "crunch": 1, "name": "E", "Bot": "", "state": "test"],
    ["test": 6, "id": 235, "total": 1, "crunch": 1, "name": "F", "Bot": "", "state": "test"]
]


let dicts = Dictionary(grouping: playersStatusData, by: {$0["state"] as! String})

print(dicts["test"]) // O/P of all state = test in array
print(dicts["original"]) // O/P of all state = original in array
```

---

If any issue then you can ask.

Comment: yeah, its coming. But why i was not able to append to my aarray of dic? `Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]?' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'`

Comment: Didn't understand your issue. Please specify more.

Comment: Nothing, got the idea..Thank youu